# Search input loses focus after setState

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When the user enters more than 3 characters and the `setSearchValue` hook fires, the input loses focus, is there a way to prevent this?

```
const handleOnChange = (value) => {
    setLocalSearchValue(value);
    if (value.length >= 3) {
      debouncedGetPlaces(value);
      setSearchValue(value);
    }
    if (value.length < 3 && value.length > 0 && searchValue.length > 0) {
      setSearchValue('');
    }
  };
  return (
    <SearchLocationInput
      onBackPress={handleBack}
      onChangeText={handleOnChange}
      placeholder={placeHolder}
      value={localSearchValue}
    />
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This can se resolved as preventing the input from losing focus when the `setSearchValue` hook fires, you can utilize the `useEffect` hook to set the focus explicitly after the state update. This ensures that the focus is maintained even after the state changes.**

You can refer to [this](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef) for more information.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

 const RenderComponent = () => {

  const [localSearchValue, setLocalSearchValue] = useState('');
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');

  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const handleOnChange = (value) => {
    setLocalSearchValue(value);

    if (value.length >= 3) {
      debouncedGetPlaces(value);
      setSearchValue(value);
    }

    if (value.length < 3 && value.length > 0 && searchValue.length > 0) {
      setSearchValue('');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [localSearchValue]);

  return (
    <SearchLocationInput
      ref={inputRef} 
      onBackPress={handleBack}
      onChangeText={handleOnChange}
      placeholder={placeHolder}
      value={localSearchValue}
    />
  );
};
```